# Where to find simple YUV (YUV420P possibly) images to test? (can I extract with ffmpeg?)

Tags: opengl, video, ffmpeg, decode

I need to test an OpenGL shader that renders YUV420P (and other YUV formats) into RGB. Decoding a video just for that would be too much.

Are there any image samples with Y, U, and V buffers for me to send to the shader?

On google I only found old websites that no longer host these images.

Maybe there's a way to easily extract a frame from any video using ffmpeg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Maybe there's a way to easily extract a frame from any video using ffmpeg?`

**(1)** For converting existing image (*eg:* PNG):

```
ffmpeg -i test.png -pix_fmt yuv420p test.yuv
```

**(2)** For converting video by frame (*eg:* extract image at video frame `xx` number):

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "select=eq(n\,xx)" -frames:v 1 test.yuv
```

**(3)** For converting video by timestamp (*eg:* extract a specific time's frame, `ss` is in `HH:MM:SS` format):

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:23:00 -i test.mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -frames:v 1 test.yuv
```

**PS:** Whether video or image, if you need a specific resolution use the video filter `scale`, where either one of those width or height in the `W:H` setting can be replaced with `-1` to keep the aspect ratio (if needed):

```
ffmpeg -i test.png -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=1280:720" test.yuv
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just generate one using ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc2=s=1280x720,format=yuv420p -vframes 1 sample.yuv
```

Note that this is planar layout, so first all Y samples, then U, then V.